# How to get sample indices from RandomUnderSampler in imblearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, imblearn

Does anyone know if/how one can get the indices of the selected samples after undersampling with imblearn's RandomUnderSampler?
There used to be the argument "return_indices=True" which was now removed for the new version and supposingly was replaced with an attribute "sample_indices_". However, if I try to use that attribute, it doesn't work (see code below). I'm using imblearn version 0.6.2.

```
russs = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=0,sampling_strategy={6: 600}).fit(X_train_point,y_train_point)
russs.sample_indices_

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-8397ba40f19b> in <module>
      1 russs = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=0,sampling_strategy={6: 600}).fit(X_train_point,y_train_point)
----> 2 russs.sample_indices

AttributeError: 'RandomUnderSampler' object has no attribute 'sample_indices'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also facing this.. Despite the fact that the docs say 
*Deprecated since version 0.4: return_indices is deprecated. Use the attribute sample_indices_ instead.*
I reverted to 0.5.0 and am able to use the old return_indices=True argument.

```
pip install imbalanced-learn==0.5.0
```

Answer (score 4):

I also found a workaround. As the undersampling is solely based on the y_vector, one can add a counter-variable instead of the the x-vector/array and write it as follows:

```
counter=range(0,len(y_train_point))
index,y_resampled=RandomUnderSampler(random_state=0,sampling_strategy={6:600}).fit(counter,y_train_point)
X_resampled=X_train_point[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem yesterday and I could access the attribute all right in the end.

Make sure you're not forgetting that underscore in the end, from the error message it seems you have.

It should be

```
russs.sample_indices_
```

not

```
russs.sample_indices
```